# How to implement Quadratic constraint in SCS for python

Tags: python, cvxopt, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, cvxpy

I have an quadratic optimisation problem of the form

min w.r.t. to x 1/2 x'x + q'x S.t. Gx <= h

I have a rather big problem ( few million points and constraints), and while cvxopt's default solver proved effective, I'm curious about implementing it in SCS which should be faster (and without using the CVXPY interface).

After a literature search (mainly Boyd's *Convex Analysis*), the reformulation to SOCP-form should yield

min w.r.t. to z  of c'z subject to Az + s = b, s in K

with c = (1 q)' and z = (t x)' where t is a scalar, and K is the cartesian product of the linear cones associated with my original constraints (Gx \leq h) and of a quadratic cone Q = { (t,x) | t >= ||x||}

However, how should I actually define A and b ?

I imagined something in the like of A = [[0 G],[2, 1, .., 1]] and b = (h 0).
However, with the 'q' option set to [1] in the python scs.solve cone dictionary argument I can't get it to work ? What is the expected syntax of A's last line? (That is, assuming my mathematical reformulation is correct...)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What does "SCS" stand for?